# Back-end permission issue with non-Admin user | typo3 8.7.24

Tags: typo3

I have been struggling to figure out what is happening about my new BE user. I have created a back-end User and give the proper permission (News administration module only) and also the ns_news_comments.

I can create News content, edit, and so on... however when the news receives a new comment to approval the backend user cannot change the News anymore. If I change the BE to Admin, it will work fine. I have already granted permission to the entire root tree.

Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are the records of ns_news_comments stored? It sounds to me as if the comments were saved as a relation to the news record and also displayed in the news record. When saving, TYPO3 fails because of the comments. It cannot update them, because the editor is not allowed to access their page / sysfolder.

Comment: TBH, I don't know where the comments are being saved. Is there any way to figure out?

Comment: A look into your database will show you the page in column "pid" of the comments table (table name tx_nsnewscomments...). I Hope, you have access to phpMyAdmin or t3adminer.

Comment: Thanks Julian. The pid is showing 0. How can I give permission to this pid?

Comment: I mean, how can I change the PID? I don't have anything on the manual... I tried to use the Record Storage Page but nothing changed.

Comment: Hey Julian, I figured out how to change the PID. I just needed to add the setup: plugin.tx_nsnewscomments.persistence.storagePid = PID and it worked like charm.

Comment: Rootpage (0) is restricted to admins. You can not grant access for "normal" BE-users